# "[vuex] state field foo was overridden by a module with the same name at foobar" with deepmerge helper function in jest

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vuex, vue-test-utils

I'm using a helper function to create a store inside my jests. The helper function uses deepmerge to merge the basic configuration with a customized configuration. This results in multiple console warnings

```
[vuex] state field "cart" was overridden by a module with the same name at "cart"
[vuex] state field "customer" was overridden by a module with the same name at "customer"
[vuex] state field "checkout" was overridden by a module with the same name at "checkout"
```

store.js (Reduced to a minimum for presentation purpose)

```
import cart from './modules/cart'
import checkout from './modules/checkout'
import customer from './modules/customer'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const config = {
    modules: {
        cart,
        customer,
        checkout,
    },
}

export default new Vuex.Store(config)
```

test-utils.js

```
import merge from 'deepmerge'
import { config as storeConfig } from './vuex/store'

// merge basic config with custom config
export const createStore = config => {
    const combinedConfig = (config)
        ? merge(storeConfig, config)
        : storeConfig
    return new Vuex.Store(combinedConfig)
}
```

making use of the helper function inside

somejest.test.js

```
import { createStore } from 'test-utils'

const wrapper = mount(ShippingComponent, {
    store: createStore({
        modules: {
            checkout: {
                state: {
                    availableShippingMethods: {
                        flatrate: {
                            carrier_title: 'Flat Rate',
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }),
    localVue,
})
```

How do I solve the console warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the warning is somewhat misleading in this case. It is technically true, just not helpful.

The following code will generate the same warning. It doesn't use `deepmerge`, `vue-test-utils` or `jest` but I believe the root cause is the same as in the original question:

```js
const config = {
  state: {},

  modules: {
    customer: {}
  }
}

const store1 = new Vuex.Store(config)
const store2 = new Vuex.Store(config)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.4.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>
```

There are two key parts of this example that are required to trigger the warning:

1. Multiple stores.
2. A root `state` object in the config.

The code in the question definitely has multiple stores. One is created at the end of `store.js` and the other is created by `createStore`.

The question doesn't show a root `state` object, but it does mention that the code has been reduced. I'm assuming that the full code does have this object.

So why does this trigger that warning?

Module `state` is stored within the root `state` object. Even though the module in my example doesn't explicitly have any `state` it does still exist. This `state` will be stored at `state.customer`. So when the first store gets created it adds a `customer` property to that root `state` object.

So far there's no problem.

However, when the second store gets created it uses the same root `state` object. Making a copy or merging the config at this stage won't help because the copied `state` will also have the `customer` property. The second store also tries to add `customer` to the root `state`. However, it finds that the property already exists, gets confused and logs a warning.

There is some coverage of this in the official documentation:

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#module-reuse

The easiest way to fix this is to use a function for the root `state` instead:

```js
state: () => ({ /* all the state you currently have */ }),
```

Each store will call that function and get its own copy of the state. It's just the same as using a `data` function for a component.

If you don't actually need root `state` you could also fix it by just removing it altogether. If no `state` is specified then Vuex will create a new root `state` object each time.

Answer (score 3):

It is logged when a property name within the state conflicts with the name of a module, like so:

```
new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    foo: 'bar'
  },
  modules: {
    foo: {}
  }
})
```

therefore this raises the warning.

```
new Vuex.Store(({
  state: {
    cart: '',
    customer: '',
    checkout: ''
  },
  modules: {
    cart: {},
    customer: {},
    checkout: {},
  }
}))
```

---

its most likely here

```
export const createStore = config => {
    const combinedConfig = (config)
        ? merge(storeConfig, config)
        : storeConfig
    return new Vuex.Store(combinedConfig)
}
```

from the source code of vuex, it helps indicate where these errors are being raised for logging.

If you run the app in production, you know that this warning wont be raised... or you could potentially intercept the warning  and immediately return;

[vuex source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/b2df4db582418ea7a9fbc8c7e46d6486f335d72b/src/store.js#L351)

```js
const parentState = getNestedState(rootState, path.slice(0, -1))
const moduleName = path[path.length - 1]
store._withCommit(() => {
  if (__DEV__) {
    if (moduleName in parentState) {
      console.warn(
        `[vuex] state field "${moduleName}" was overridden by a module with the same name at "${path.join('.')}"`
      )
    }
  }
  Vue.set(parentState, moduleName, module.state)
})
```

[vuex tests](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/b2df4db582418ea7a9fbc8c7e46d6486f335d72b/test/unit/modules.spec.js#L561-L580)

```js
jest.spyOn(console, 'warn').mockImplementation()
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    foo: {
      state () {
        return { value: 1 }
      },
      modules: {
        value: {
          state: () => 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
expect(store.state.foo.value).toBe(2)
expect(console.warn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  `[vuex] state field "value" was overridden by a module with the same name at "foo.value"`
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I believe there is no need for using `deepmerge` in test-utils.ts. It is better we use Vuex itself to handle the merging of the module instead of merging it with other methods.

If you see the documentation for [Vuex testing with Jest](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vuex.html#mocking-with-modules) on mocking modules

you need to pass the module which is required.

```
import { createStore, createLocalVue } from 'test-utils';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(Vuex);

// mock the store in beforeEach

describe('MyComponent.vue', () => {
  let actions
  let state
  let store

  beforeEach(() => {
    state = {
      availableShippingMethods: {
        flatrate: {
          carrier_title: 'Flat Rate',
        },
      },
    }

    actions = {
      moduleActionClick: jest.fn()
    }

    store = new Vuex.Store({
      modules: {
        checkout: {
          state,
          actions,
          getters: myModule.getters // you can get your getters from store. No need to mock those 
        }
      }
    })
  })
});
```

whistle, In test cases:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, { store, localVue })
```

Hope this helps!